# Sharepoint webpart deployment - activate features error

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I'm a noob to Sharepoint development, actually I hoped I'd always be a noob to it, and I'm having difficulty building my first web part for a Sharepoint 2010 website. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and I started with a Visual Web Part. All i added was a simple asp:Label control, as I just want to make sure it's deploying correctly before I go any further. It builds, says it's deploys even, and then croaks on the 'activate feature' step. I get the following error.

```
Error   1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Feature with Id '12765e82-6e4a-4407-aa8c-77b537841f4b' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope. 0   0   scCodePart
```

There isn't much out there to go by for help on this. I made sure the scope of the feature was set to 'Site', as was recommended. I even tried changing the xml of Feature1.Template.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature Id="12765e82-6e4a-4407-aa8c-77b537841f4b" Scope="Site" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
</Feature>
```

And the error persists. I read something about the web.config of the site might causing it, but it provided no explanation as to why. Any thoughts?

*EDIT*

There is my Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="scClosetCodesVWP" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="scClosetCodesVWP\scClosetCodesVWP.webpart" Url="scClosetCodesVWP.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

and my Feature1.Template.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
</Feature>
```

I haven't altered either one of them from what Visual Studio initially creates. I tried declaring the id & scope in Feature1.Template.xml, but i got the same error after.

Comment: To everyone now seeing this question, the problem was there being multiple servers on the same farm, or something like that. Once your in that situation, you can forget about publishing a webpart. SharePoint 2010 ending up being the reason I left the position I was at when I asked this question, I don't want anything to do with it. I suggest you all start looking into Umbraco or Orchard for your CMS needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kindly go through the following URL which has complete solution for your problem

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2008/04/02/server-error-feature-guid-is-not-installed-in-this-farm-and-cannot-be-added-to-this-scope.aspx

Comment: using the STSADM.EXE tool actual did get it to show up as a control in the list, but it brought up another error when i tried to add it to a page. I've tried it at every scope.

Comment: 1. stsadm.exe -o retractsolution -name <<yourwspname>> -immediate 
2. stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs
3. stsadm.exe –o addsolution –filename <<your wsp path>>
4. stsadm.exe –o deploysolution –name <<yourwspname>> -allowgacdeployment -immediate
5.   stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs and then activate your feature manually

Comment: I'm getting "command line error" when I try "stsadm.exe –o addsolution –filename C:\temp\scCodePart1\bin\Debug\scCodePart1.wsp" am I typing this wrong somehow?

Comment: file name should be in double quotes not full statement

Comment: ahh, my error was a copy/paste problem. I got the addsolution to work, on the deploysolution command I get the following: "This solution contains resources scoped for a Web application and must be deployed to one or more Web applications" I thought thats what I was doing?

Comment: I tried "stsadm.exe -o deploysolution -name <mypart.wsp> -url <myurl> -allowgacdeployment -immediate" and it said it worked, but it hasn't shown up yet. I tried running the execadmsvcjobs, but I don't think it's working right.

Comment: just check the log from 14 hive folder and let me know what error message  you got for deployments

Comment: Well, it says it deployed now, but I don't see it as a web part option when I edit a page in the site

Comment: you would have to activate the feature which was deployed by your wsp look into the features gallery depending upon the scope set by you

Comment: oh my God, it actually worked. thanks for your help, although this definitely isn't the super-easy process I keep hearing about. I would like to know why it can't just deploy like it supposedly does for everyone else.

Comment: This might also be cause by a conflicting feature id. I solved it by simply deleting the feature and adding a new one. Make sure to retract and delete the solution in the solution gallery before you do this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the incorrect scope set for your feature. Take a look [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2007/05/03/sharepoint-features-elements-scope-and-other-info.aspx) to see what features can be deployed at what scope.

Simplest way is just to weak that scope setting, redeploy and see if you get a better result :)

Answer (score 0):

if you have farm admin privilages, you can goto the Central Admin -> System Settings -> Manage Farm Solutions
Select Project.wsp file and click on Deploy Solution

Depending the feature scope setting, go there to activate it.
For Example, if its site collection level, goto site collection settings and activate it.

Alternately you can also use powershell to do the same thing.